# Why div (s) do not get up in PopUp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I did this: https://codepen.io/Maxim22/pen/aEbxEv

div (s) with video do not stand in PopUp, and if you change the size of the window a little, then they are located as needed.
What is the reason, and how to solve through CSS ?

```
<a href="#test-popup" class="open-popup-link">Открыть Окно с Видео</a>
<div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">

    <p>PopUp works on magnificPopup (please see link) </p> 

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided

```
.block {
//Added by
      max-height: 490px;
    }
```